# Check what files are compiled during "make"

Tags: android, unix, makefile, compilation

I am trying to port pulseaudio to Android. I have compiled pulse audio on Ubuntu and it works fine with my build. However, I want to do this on Android and for that I need the list of files that are compiled during "make". I have disabled a lot of optional components by passing args to `configure`.

Is there an easy way to find the list of files that are being compiled so that I can use them on Android and discard rest of the files.

I know the hard way to do this using a `strace` and look for all `open` calls for `.c` files, but that obviously is not a good option (especially when the file count is very high).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `make -Bn`, you should see all the compiled files.